# Setting boolean in Duplicates of nested List

Tags: c#, linq

I Have a List of Site. In that class i have List of Point.

First i want to compare each Site if they are on the same Layer. My query should already do it. Now that i know i have Sites that are on the same Layer i want to check each Point of each Site to the other Sites Points and check if they have the same "coords". If they do i want to set the Boolean "isObsolete" to true.

```
Ex.: (Pseudocode)

Site1

Layer = Layer.First
List<Point> points
{
    new Point(new Vector2(15.0f, 15.0f))
    new Point(new Vector2(16.4f, 63.1f))
}


Site2
Layer = Layer.First
List<Point> points
{
    new Point(new Vector2(1.4f, 28.2f))
    new Point(new Vector2(15.0f, 15.0f))
}

-> Site1.Point1 == Site2.Point2
-> therefore both booleans are set to true.
```

```
public class LinqTesting
{
    public class Site
    {
        public List<Point> edges;
        public Layer Layer;

        public Site(List<Point> edges, Layer layer)
        {
            this.edges = edges;
            this.Layer = layer;
        }
    }

    public class Point
    {
        public Vector2 coords;
        public bool isObsolete = false;

        public Point(Vector2 coords)
        {
            this.coords = coords;
        }

     public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if(obj is Point)
            {
                var point = (Point)obj;
                float epsilon = 0.01f;

                if (Mathf.Abs(point.coords.x - this.coords.x) < epsilon
                    && Mathf.Abs(point.coords.y - this.coords.y) < epsilon)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public enum Layer
    {
        First, Second, Third, Fourth
    }

    public List<Point> point1 = new List<Point>()
    {
        new Point(new Vector2(12.2f, 25.6f)),
        new Point(new Vector2(14.2f, 19.1f)),
    };

    public List<Point> point2 = new List<Point>()
    {
        new Point(new Vector2(12.2f, 25.6f)),
        new Point(new Vector2(16.2f, 19.1f)),
    };

    public List<Point> point3 = new List<Point>()
    {
        new Point(new Vector2(13.2f, 25.6f)),
        new Point(new Vector2(16.2f, 19.1f)),
    };

    public List<Site> sites = new List<Site>();

    void Start()
    {
        sites.Add(new Site(point1, Layer.First));
        sites.Add(new Site(point2, Layer.First));
        sites.Add(new Site(point3, Layer.Second));

        var query = sites.GroupBy(x => x.Layer)
            .Where(group => group.Count() > 1)
            .Select(grp => grp.ToList());

        // I now have List<Site> duplicateValues grouped by duplicated layers

        // EDIT: This works. Not the most elegant way with 3 foreach loops. Any way to make it cleaner?
        // I also added override Equals to point.

        foreach (List<Site> siteLayer in query)
        {
            foreach (Site site in siteLayer)
            {
                foreach (Point point in site.points)
                {
                    siteLayer.Where(x => x != site)
                        .SelectMany(x => x.points)
                        .Where(x => x.Equals(point))
                        .ToList()
                        .ForEach(x => x.isObsolete = true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I struggle to correctly understand your two criteria. You say `the "Site" that contains the "Point" has the same "Layer"` The same layer as what? You also say `the "Point" of another "Site" has the same Vector2 coordinates.` Is there an implication that the other site must have the same layer as the site the point is from, as your code suggests? Also, are the two criteria logically OR (only one of the criteria needs to apply) or logically AND (both criteria have to apply)?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I have a List<Site>. First criteria is for comparing each Sites is that they are on the Same Layer, which my query should do already. Then, if Sites are on the Same Layer we need to Check their Points. For example Site1 has 5 Points. Site2 has 5 Points. Then i want to Check every point on Site1 if there is a Duplicate in the List<Point> in Site2. If there is, i set both Bools in these Points to true. So Yeah they logically AND. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, i think i got it now. If you edit your question with the clarifications (you don't need to do it now on the phone), drop me a comment and i'll try to answer..

Comment: I have updated the post. I hope it is clear enough :)

Comment: Hey @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace i updated again. This piece of code is working now. Do you have any tips on how to improve the code?

Comment: (1/3) Oh, you already came up with a working solution. Great! Since your code is now working and you seem to be interested in how to improve it further, i suggest to hop over to **https://codereview.stackexchange.com** and ask for review of your code there.
Just a few pointers here already: The three foreach loops are not "not elegant". They are not beautiful, either, but they are functional, and more importantly _readable_.
Perf-wise the Linq stuff you do in the innermost loop will become more of a real performance killer the more sites/points in total are present in a layer.

Comment: (2/3) Currently, for every single point from the innermost foreach loop, the Linq-stuff there iterates over _all_ points in the same same layer _again_ and creates a new temp list. This costs. You perhaps want to think of a scheme involving look-ups (perhaps a Dictionary or a HashSet) that will avoid doing this inner Linq at all.
And if you were to decide that you want a HashSet of Points or use them as keys in dictionaries or something similar where the points serve as looked-up values, just overriding the `Equals` method of `Point` is not sufficient.

Comment: (3/3) You will also need to override the `GetHashCode` method accordingly. Pay utmost attention to GetHashCode's documentation wrt to implementing it correctly, otherwise using Point's in HashSets or as dictionary keys won't work properly. All that said, perhaps you are toally happy with the current perf characteristics. Perhaps the performance of this routine doesn't matter, perhaps it is only executed once as part of some initialization and doesn't impact the operation of the app. I dont't know. If performance is not a concern, feel free to ignore everything i just said in my last 3 comments